# How to properly use Material-UI transition components when rendering conditionally

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I'm trying to use the MUI Zoom transition component for a bingo card, where the content of the card changes when the user completes all of the squares.  I've included some test code to show the problem that I'm having. The original content transitions correctly (`showFront === true`), but when the content is re-rendered (`showFront === false`), the zoom transition does not trigger a second time:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Zoom from '@mui/material/Zoom';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';


const testCard = [
  { front: '10 Push-ups', back: 'exercise', id: 1 },
  { front: 'Black climb', back: 'colour', id: 2 },
  { front: 'C2.2 climb', back: 'climb', id: 3 },
  { front: 'Purple climb', back: 'colour', id: 4 },
  { front: 'Intro', back: 'climb', id: 5 },
  { front: 'All the intros', back: 'intros', id: 6 },
  { front: 'C1 climb', back: 'climb', id: 7 },
  { front: 'Yellow climb', back: 'colour', id: 8 },
  { front: 'Red climb', back: 'colour', id: 9 },
  { front: '5 Pull-ups', back: 'exercise', id: 10 },
  { front: 'White climb', back: 'colour', id: 11 },
  { front: 'Intro climb', back: 'climb', id: 12 },
];

export default function Test() {
  const [showFront, setShowFront] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => setShowFront(prev => !prev)}>
        Flip
      </Button>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, mt:3 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          {testCard.map((challenge) => (
            <Grid item key={challenge.id} xs={3}>
              {showFront
                ?
                <Zoom in={showFront} style={{ transitionDelay: challenge.id * 200 }}>
                  <Typography variant="body2">
                    {challenge.front}
                  </Typography>
                </Zoom>
                :
                <Zoom in={!showFront} style={{ transitionDelay: challenge.id * 200 }}>
                  <Typography variant="body2">
                    {challenge.back}
                  </Typography>
                </Zoom>
              }
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

There are no errors showing in the console (front-end or back-end). I played around with the React Transaction Group component, but couldn't find a solution that way. This is my first project with MUI, so any help would be greatly appreciated!